# How get a list of users who are monitoring checkin of a particular directory

Tags: perforce

I like to get all the names who are monitoring checkin of a particular directory, i.e. the persons getting email notification when there is checkin in that directory.

Any pointer?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways:

1. Make a submission to that directory, and look at the email that is sent out to see who is on the list.
2. or, run 'p4 reviews //that/particular/directory/...' and look at the results.

Comment: Not sure if it is configuration problem in my company, when I run p4 reviews, I get many names most of which I am sure are not subscribing to the directory.

Comment: Add the email "To" field is empty, I guess this is how my company IT configures perforce.  Thanks though.